# How to ignor Warnings when I use load_file() in Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I use SIMPLE HTML DOM.
Some pages take a long time -> then Warning (HTTP request failed) -> find() doesn`t work! FATAL ERROR!
How to go to the next page?

```
$items = [...];
foreach ($item as $link) {
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html -> load_file($link);
    if (WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE TO START PARSING WHEN $html is OK?) {
        some parsing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line `$html -> load_file($link);` is the one causing the page timeout, you can do nothing on the next line.

Maybe consider increasing the `set_time_limit` or deactivating it `set_time_limit(0)` before the `foreach`loop.

```
$items = [...];
set_time_limit(300);
foreach ($item as $link) {
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html -> load_file($link);
    if (WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE TO START PARSING WHEN $html is OK?) {
        some parsing
    }
}
```

You should read the [set_time_limit documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and [max execution time documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Be aware that increasing this value in a web context may not be a great idea. Also, be aware that according to PHP documentation, apache seems to have a timeout at 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Comment: set_time_limit() can`t help me. Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded. All i need to know - is my object valid for function find() or not?